# Javascript calculations even if browser closed

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

**My Scenario**

Right so this questions has spawned because im making a game. I am slightly (Not So Slightly) addicted to Orteils game Cookie Clicker and decided that i want to become good at javascript and eventually make my own game.

So far the developments going good but i've come across a problem (The Title Of This Post). Orteils cookie clicker allows the user to close the browser and keep track of how long you were away and gives you cookies based on your Cps (Cookies per second) * time you were away.

As a beginner i have no idea how he's gone about this but i find it interesting and would like to use it in my project.

**My Question**

How do you calculate the time that the browser has been closed for, or keep a script of some sort running in the background for as long as it needs to as long as people dont have the page open.

The game in question can be found [Here](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)

Comment: `the browser has been closed` - you mean, not on your page

Comment: You don't need to run anything in the background- at a high level, just store the time that the game was closed somewhere, and when the game is started next, load that value and subtract it from the current time to get the difference and do your action. But note that you should do this server-side, since otherwise I could just change my PC's clock to fool the game into giving me more cookies..

Comment: you could save the current time in ms when the browser closes then when the game starts again, look if it has a time saved, calculate the difference and then work out how many cookies you would get when it reopens?

Comment: Can't help to feel like this post is also an add for Cookie Clicker.

Comment: @charlietfl he described it in his post: a way to track how long the user was *not* using the app between uses.

Comment: @Mouser Its actually not lol I advise all of you to stay well away from this game

Comment: @mast3rd3mon How will i be able to save the time that the browser window was closed server side? For example if chrome was closed surely i wouldnt be able to make an ajax call to make this save..?

Comment: @KarlReid Wow I do tend to overthink things when i have no idea how it works, this makes perfect sense to me, other than what i said to mast3rd3mon, How will i be able to perform any actions if the browser has just been closed. If im going to save server side i would make an ajax request to the server to store the "close time" essentially but if its closed would this not be a problem?

Comment: every 5 or 10 seconds, log the time maybe? or use the `unload` property of the body tag?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Thats a great idea actually i cant believe i didnt think of that, for some reason i felt javascript had extremely different properties to PHP and i was treating it as such. Thanks for this though, put this as the answer along with your previous post and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the current time in ms when the browser closes then when the game starts again, look if it has a time saved, calculate the difference and then work out how many cookies you would get when it reopens.

To do this, you could save the time every 5 or 10 seconds or use the `unload` property of the body tag. The `unload` property will call a method once the webpage or browser has been closed.